# Image quality help - Android

Tags: android, image, photo

I have a photo editing app. All it does is add images onto a base photo. The output photo is lower quality than the original photo which is taken by the camera. This is expected, but maybe I can improve on what I currently have. It's the same quality at 500px as 1000px which is very concerning... I can see I'm limiting quality somewhere other than pixels. The original photos in my camera gallery are JPG files. Here is everything I do to get the photo, create the bitmap from it, and then save it. Can you tell me where in the code the photo quality may get lower?

open gallery intent:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

OnActivityResult() for the chosen photo:

```
    if (intent != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK) 
                          {
                              mProfilePicPath = ih.getSelectedImageFilePathFromGallery(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
                              mPortraitPhoto = ih.decodeSampledBitmapFromImagePath(mProfilePicPath, 
                                      GlobalConstants.PROFILE_PICTURE_RESOLUTION, 
                                      GlobalConstants.PROFILE_PICTURE_RESOLUTION);
                          }

        public String getSelectedImageFilePathFromGallery(Context ctx,
                    Intent intent) {
                Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                return filePath;
            }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromImagePath(String imagePath, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

            int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
            int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
            String imageType = options.outMimeType;
            Log.d("Image dims", imageType + ", " + imageHeight + ", " + imageWidth + "size.");

            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            Bitmap portraitPhoto = ImageHelper.convertToPortraitOrientation(options, imagePath);
            return portraitPhoto;

        }

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}

    public static Bitmap convertToPortraitOrientation(BitmapFactory.Options options, String path) {
            Uri actualUri = Uri.parse(path);
            float degree = 0;

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
            try {
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(actualUri.getPath());
                String exifOrientation = exif
                        .getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);

                if (bmp != null) {
                    degree = getDegree(exifOrientation);
                    if (degree != 0)
                        bmp = createRotatedBitmap(bmp, degree);
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bmp;
        }

    public static Bitmap createRotatedBitmap(Bitmap bm, float degree) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            if (degree != 0) {
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.preRotate(degree);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                        bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

    public File createProfilePicSaveFileInternal(Context ctx) {

            //mBackgroundImage.setImageBitmap(ih.decodeSampledBitmapFromImagePath(mProfilePicPath, 500, 500));


            String path = ctx.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "My Folder";
            File outputDir= new File(path);
            outputDir.mkdirs();
            File newFile = new File(path + "/" + mName + ".jpg");

            return newFile;
        }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        public void saveImage( Bitmap bitmap, Context ctx, File newFile) {
            FileOutputStream fos;
            newFile.setReadable(true, false);
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            ctx.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

        }
```

when a button is clicked:

```
    File newInternalFile = ih.createProfilePicSaveFileInternal(this.getApplicationContext());
            boolean s = newInternalFile.exists();
            long length = newInternalFile.length();
            ih.saveImage(mPortraitPhoto, this.getApplicationContext(), newInternalFile);
            mPortraitPhoto = null;

public File createProfilePicSaveFileInternal(Context ctx) {

        //mBackgroundImage.setImageBitmap(ih.decodeSampledBitmapFromImagePath(mProfilePicPath, 500, 500));


        String path = ctx.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "My Folder";
        File outputDir= new File(path);
        outputDir.mkdirs();
        File newFile = new File(path + "/" + mName + ".jpg");

        return newFile;
    }
```

After my image is first saved, I then get that saved image in it's true form by doing this (inSampleSize is now 1):

```
public Bitmap getPortraitBitmapNotSampled(String imagePath){
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

        int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
        String imageType = options.outMimeType;
        Log.d("Dressing room photo dims", imageType + ", " + imageHeight + ", " + imageWidth + "size.");

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = 1;

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap portraitPhoto = ImageHelper.convertToPortraitOrientation(options, imagePath);
        return portraitPhoto;
    }
```

I end up taking a screen shot to get the output image like this:

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
        View v = findViewById(R.id.DressBig);
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return v.getDrawingCache();
    }
```

Then the final save:

```
private void saveClicked(){
        finishedOutfit = takeScreenshot();
        File newFile = ih.createOutfitSaveFileExternal();
        File newInternalFile = ih.createOutfitSaveFileInternal(this.getApplicationContext());
        ih.saveImage(finishedOutfit, this.getApplicationContext(), newFile);
        ih.saveImage(finishedOutfit, this.getApplicationContext(), newInternalFile);
        String newFilePath = newInternalFile.toString();
        String newExternalFilePath = newFile.toString();
        Log.d("db file path: ", newFilePath);
        Log.d("external file path: ", newExternalFilePath);
        insertOutfitInDB(newFilePath, newExternalFilePath);
        showImageSavedDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have examples of "before" and "after" images? Being able to see the loss in quality you speak of may give some clue as to if it is due to JPEG compression or some other source.

Comment: @Glenn Thanks. I will put those comparison photos up now. Do you think I should check what file type the gallery photo is and try to keep it that file type?

Comment: It all depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you want a homogeneous set of images of the same size and format, keeping the filetype is counterproductive. If you want to keep the same image quality, reading and writing a JPEG in this manner is very dangerous, because you are re-compressing already compressed data, which is never good news.

Comment: After we see comparison photos, we'll hopefully know more. Also, some information about Cropper may prove to be helpful.

Comment: @Glenn Thanks. Photos up. I also added more code i used. Now all the code I use on the images is there. Sorry it is lots. Was work for me to get it all lol.

Comment: GlobalConstants.PROFILE_PICTURE_RESOLUTION what is this value, and the sampleSize output. this is where u are getting smaller version of the image. try removing these and see if u can the original image quality

Comment: @PulkitSethi No change in quality when having a higher resolution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you see here is definitely caused by JPEG compression artifacts. You can see this by the characteristic 8x8 pixel blocks formed that you can see when zooming in.

JPEGs are tricky. They have very good compression ratios, but they use these 8x8 blocks for compression (technical: the 8x8 block is the area of the quantized discrete cosine transform used for content encoding). When a JPEG is opened and saved again, these blocks are re-compressed.

Normally, if the same image is opened, saved, and closed multiple times, there won't be a gigantic difference in image quality. This is because the same blocks are encoded and quantized identically, so the lost information was already lost.

However, if a JPEG image is cropped so that the 8x8 artifacting is no longer aligned with the 8x8 compression grid used, then things get really messy. The JPEG compressor won't understand that it should really be compressing a grid shifted by a few pixels, and will try to mash pieces of each of the old blocks into new blocks. In this case, there's a LOT of information that is again quantized, and you get some very significant degredation.

The simplest way to (mostly) avoid this artifacting when working with JPEGs is to enforce alignment with the 8x8 image grid when cropping. However, if you really want to get lossless-quality cropping, you have to manipulate the un-decompressed DCT blocks inside the JFIF wrapper. It's ugly, but doable. I do not know of an Android implementation of this, however.

**Takeaway: JPEGs are finicky when cropped and recompressed - try to force alignment with an 8x8 grid to reduce quality loss.**

Comment: Thanks! I can switch from JPEG if you recommend? How do I force alignment with an 8x8 grid? Can I get a starting point? I really do not want a big difficult task, and will consider doing nothing if the only fix is big and difficult. I have time constraints. But I certainly would like to improve it somehow.

Comment: If I remove the cropper, can I then do nothing and get better quality? This is very possible for me to do.

Comment: Please note I am adding images on top of the original image. That is all the editing I am doing. Thanks!

Comment: For a "quick-and-dirty" solution, if you do not have to crop the images, don't. For an easy solution that will allow you to crop them, just make sure that the change in number of pixels in each dimension is (to be completely safe) a factor of 16.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot control the pixels to the nearest pixel. When I use insampleSize 500px X 500Px, it just goes to near that, so like 812 X 621 as an example. I don't really need to crop. [Especially if I fix this issue (my other question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278537/adding-a-view-to-relativelayout-changes-its-size) . I would like to fix that issue anyway as cropping out black strips looks unprofessional. If you have a look at that question I would be very greatful :) Thanks.

Comment: I think maybe cropping suits me more. If you can hint at how to set the pixels to an exact factor of 16 I would be very appreciative, however you have helped me enough already. As I said, my inSampleSize technique will not set the pixels to a factor of 16, thank you.

Comment: Either that or not using JPEG, maybe PNG, if that is better when not keeping it to a factor of 16. Cheers.

Comment: a PNG will not have the same compression issue, though you are going to add a different sort of compression on top of the JPEG compression.
I'm not an Android developer, so I don't have any information about how to crop more effectively. Sorry, and good luck!

Comment: I only compress it once. I no longer crop. I got rid of the black strips so don't need to crop them out. The image is just as bad as ever. So you think PNG might help? I will try that now. Is there any way to know the absolute best filetype to use? Thanks :)

Comment: I just found out the images in my phones gallery are jpg type. So keeping them as that should be better for quality I would have thought. No compression used/no changing them.