# Adding a View to RelativeLayout changes its size

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a RelativeLayout called "Dress" with LayoutParams of WRAP_CONTENT. All that is inside it is an ImageView, so it is the same size as the ImageView. When I add one more view to the RelativeLayout in OnCreate, like this:

```
photoSorter = new MultitouchImagesView(this.getApplicationContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ((ViewGroup) findViewById(id.Dress)).addView(photoSorter, params);
```

The RelativeLayout called Dress changes size, to take up the whole RootView, basically the whole activity, minus the actionbar.

I take a screenshot of the Dress Layout. So when photoSorter is in the RootLayout (NOT the Dress Layout) like this:

```
photoSorter = new MultitouchImagesView(this.getApplicationContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        addContentView(photoSorter, params);
```

Layout Dress is correct size and I get this screenshot which is what I want:

[image]

But I need PhotoSorter in the Dress Layout so that I can include it in my screenshot and not have the black strips. When I add the photoSortr to the Dress Layout like this:

```
photoSorter = new MultitouchImagesView(this.getApplicationContext());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ((ViewGroup) findViewById(id.Dress)).addView(photoSorter, params);
```

It makes the Dress Layout take up the whole screen so the screenshot of the Dress Layout looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code to take a screenshot:

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
        View v = findViewById(R.id.Dress);
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return v.getDrawingCache();
    }
```

Here is my XML for the activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:onClick="deleteImage"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Dress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewDress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#00CED1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView 
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also When I added com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView to the DressLayout, it made the Dress Layout take up the whole activity as well. So adding anything to the Dress Layout is making it bigger.

How can I add photoSorter to the Dress Layout without making Dress Layout take up the whole activity size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed by trying things out in XML. The key is to align Dress with imageViewDress, I could align the other sides to be more thorough, not just bottom.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
        tools:context=".DressingRoomActivity" >

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/DressBig"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewDress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

             <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Dress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewDress"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
             </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView 
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This XML, then add photoSorter to Dress programmatically, then take a screenshot of DressBig.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Dress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="...">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewDress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

EDIT:

You can add the below rule to your params so it's laid out over the other content if that's what you want. This is my third attempt at trying to figure out what you're asking for so if it's not what you need, you'll have to figure it out yourself seeing as you are being lazy and won't do a sketch to try and explain clearly how you want it laid out

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
```

Comment: Thanks :) I will just explain these things about my app. Changing the image ratio or cropping is out of the question. That doesn't happen because I'm not wanting to fit the image to the screensize. It goes to the width of the screen and then the height just stops where it stops. So it goes to around 90% of the screen size. Then I take a snapshot of just the ImageView and the PhotoSorter. The Dress Layout is necessary to take a snapshot the size of the ImageView that also contains the PhotoSorter view. Not a screen shot the size of the activity. I will give this a go.

Comment: No such luck but thanks for having a go. match_parent would make happen what you thought I wanted (the full screen image).

Comment: Try what I've done in my edited answer, fitXY should size the image as you've described, then the dress view can contain the background and make sure there are no black lines

Comment: I've just realised I was not understanding your question, I think I understand what you want now but if you could attach a sketch of how the finished layout should look so I can be sure, then I can help

Comment: Thanks. The screenshot I take of Dress Layout will be just like my top photo I posted. But not because the image goes to the screen size. Because the rest of the screen is cut out of the screenshot. This is achieved by making the Dress Layout the same size as the ImageView (by making it wrap_content). The extra view I add (photoSorter) is what adds extra images to the activity that will appear in the screenshot too and that is why I need the PhotoSorter inside the Dress Layout, but when I do add it in OnCreate, it seems to make the DressLayout full-screen-sized.

Comment: It seems like you *need* the whole screen in the screenshot and that the photosorter should fill all the remaining space. If that's not what you want then post a sketch like I said, repeating your original post doesn't help - showing the output screenshot and sayign something is missing from it doesn't really tell me anything

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to sketch, and what you don't understand. I want the photoSorter to match the size of the ImageView and the DressLayout when it's the size of the ImageView. I don;t want the PhotoSorter to go big and force the DressLayout to go big. But i don't know how to make this happen so might have to just crop out black bits.

Comment: so what you're saying - that you haven't mentioned in your question - is that you don't care how it looks on screen, only about the screenshot? In that case I imagine you can add a rule to your params to fix the issue. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: I do care how it looks on the screen. I want photoSortr in my DressLayout which changes the look. I asked my question clearly down the bottom of the question "How can I add photoSorter to the Dress Layout without making Dress Layout take up the whole activity size?" That pretty much answers how I want it laid out. The same as it is in the XML...but adding a child to Dress layout, and the question title "how can I add a child to a layout without changing the Layouts size" explains it. Thank you however for attempting to answer my question multiple times.

Comment: That doesn't tell anything about layout, that just describes one side affect you want to avoid. Is it to be displayed above the image? below? beside? centred? Any of those layouts change the answer slightly. If you are going to ask for help you should at least try to help yourself. That includes clearing up the question if asked. Just because it makes sense in your head doesn't mean it clearly describes the problem to somebody who has never seen it!

Comment: The whole question is about avoiding that side-effect...Why does my question have to be about the layout. "But I need PhotoSorter in the Dress Layout so that I can include it in my screenshot and not have the black strips. When I add the photoSortr to the Dress Layout like this...It makes the Dress Layout take up the whole screen so the screenshot of the Dress Layout looks like this". That clearly states on top of the image so you see it, but not above it, not below it or beside it, so the black strips disappear.